# sama5d3 pwm refuses to work

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, pwm

I'm using a SAMA5D31-EK board and I'm trying to have the SAMA5D31 internal PWM controller output a signal through a PIO pin: specifically PE31. The board is running Linux 3.10.0+ and I'm managing the PWM using sysfs interface. This interface seems to perform correctly: I can create the device (writing to 'export' file), activate it, change the contents of period and duty_cycle files (when read back they contain latest values written to them).
As for the configuration of PIO PE31 I've changed arch/arm/boot/dts/sama5d3.dtsi file to include

```
pwm0 {
    pinctrl_pwml1: pwml1-0 {
    atmel,pins =
        <AT91_PIOE 31 AT91_PERIPH_B AT91_PINCTRL_NONE>;  /*PE31*/
    };
};
                pwm0: pwm@f002c000 {
                        compatible = "atmel,sama5d3-pwm";
                        reg = <0xf002c000 0x300>;
                        interrupts = <28 IRQ_TYPE_LEVEL_HIGH 4>;
                        #pwm-cells = <3>;
                        status = "disabled";
                };
```

Status of pwm0 is also changed from "disabled" to "okay" in sama5d31.dts file

Somewhere on the Internet I've learn that this behaviour might be related to a missing clock definition in those dts files. Somewhere else I've read that I need to upgrade to 3.11 or 3.12 kernel.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Joan.

Comment: Finally I succeeded in having that PWM working; or more precisely: in having the PWM output signal available through a PIO pin.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I managed to have that PWM working; or more precisely: obtaining the PWM output signal through a GPIO pin.

The dts code above has two problems. Firstly PE31 (the chosen GPIO pin) was being used by another process. But more important: the PWM controller node was missing some pinctrl definitions and the correct number of pwm-cells (5). It should read as:

```
                pwm0: pwm@f002c000 {
                        compatible = "atmel,sama5d3-pwm";
                        reg = <0xf002c000 0x300>;
                        interrupts = <28 IRQ_TYPE_LEVEL_HIGH 4>;
                        pinctrl-names = "default";
                        pinctrl-0 = <&pinctrl_pwmh1>;
                        #pwm-cells = <5>;
                        status = "disabled";
                };
```

BR,
Joan